# Select all child elements with all attributes of child elements in a table.

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Suppose I have the following xml:

```
<parent>
    <child1 attr1="value" attr2="value" attr3="value"/>
    <child1 attr1="value" attr2="value" attr3="value"/>
    <child1 attr1="value" attr2="value" attr3="value"/>
</parent>
```

I want to put all elements of type **child1** as rows into a table consisting of a column for each attribute - simple enough. My problem, however, is that the type of child element and the number/types of the child elements attributes vary between instances of **parent**. Here's an example of what some instances of **parent** might contain

```
<parent>
    <child2 attr1="value" attr2="value" attr3="value" attr4="value"/>
    <child2 attr1="value" attr2="value" attr3="value" attr4="value"/>
    <child2 attr1="value" attr2="value" attr3="value" attr4="value"/>
</parent>
```

The good news is that there will never be two types of child elements within parent, so as long as I have a when clause for each possible type of child element and its associated attributes, I can make this work. The bad news is there are a lot of variations on the child element and its going to take a long time to ensure that I've accounted for every single one of them.

My question is this - is there any way to indiscriminately do a for each that selects all child elements without looking for a specific type while selecting all of the child elements attributes into a table format automatically without specificying following for each attribute explicitly within the foreach:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="attr1"/></td>
```

This would then hopefully result in varying types of tables depending on the type of child element within the parent instance and its associated variation of attributes.

Is this possible or am I out of luck?

Comment: This is somewhat confusing: will there be more than one parent in a single document? If yes, how many tables do you want to have in the end? One table for each parent, or a single table (with rows of differing width?) for all? Also, when you say *"I want to put all elements of type **child1** as rows into a table*" it is not clear if there will be *other* child elements present, and if yes - how can you select the ones you want, when obviously the name changes from parent to parent.

Comment: I was actually mistaken on the content but yes there will be many parent elements. What I did not realize is that there actually can be multiple types of child elements within a single parent. Basically, at this point, I'm just going to compile a list of all possible variations which will take some time but will also allow me to format everything in a nicer way in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible.  Let's say you want each `<parent>` node to turn into a `<table>`. (Obviously, you will adjust your `select` XPath to where your `parent` nodes really are in the incoming document).

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="indoc/parent"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="parent">
     <table>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </table>
 </xsl:template>
```

Now, let's also say that you really care about the element names, and only want to turn `childnnn` nodes into rows. We'll do a `for-each` to turn each attribute (the `@*` XPath) into a `<td>`.

```
 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'child')]">
     <tr>
         <xsl:for-each select="@*">
             <td>
                 <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(), ':', .)"/>
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

If you really want *every* node under `<parent>` to turn into a row, no matter what the element name is, you can either condense this into a two-level nested `for-each`, or use template modes:

```
 <xsl:template match="parent">
     <table>
         <xsl:apply-templates mode="make-row" />
     </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="make-row">
     <tr>
         <xsl:for-each select="@*">
             <td>
                 <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(), ':', .)"/>
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```